# How to create a shared volume between docker host and container in Mac

Tags: docker, share, volume

I am running DockerHost, docker container on Mac OS X. I have exposed my Mac's `/mnt/vol1` (directory) as `/mnt_vol1` in the docker container, and it shows up fine. However, the files I write in container volume do not reflect in DockerHost and vice-versa

```
docker run  -it -v /mnt/vol1:/mnt_vol1 --name exposed_volume gopal/ubuntu:v2 /bin/bash
```

docker inspect showsup correctly:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Source": "/mnt/vol1",
        "Destination": "/mnt_vol1",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    }
],
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using boot2docker / docker toolbox or the Docker for Mac beta? If you're using Docker Toolbox, only the `/Users` directory is shared with the Virtual Machine that the docker daemon runs in, anything outside that is not accessible by the virtual machine (by default), and results in docker creating an *empty* directory inside the Virtual Machine, and mounting that inside the container

Comment: Thanks. I am using the ToolBox. I was also checking the documentation that says it is possible, but is an involved process.

Comment: You may be interested in https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/ which resolves a lot of issues in this area; e.g. you can use any directory on your Mac